# How to copy an external XML inside another using XSLT processor?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have this first xml **file1.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node1>
     <node2>
     </node2>
</node1>
```

And this second xml **file2.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node2>
    <node3>
    </node3>
</node2>
```

I want to have this after XSLT processing :

```
<node1>
    <node2>
        <node3>
        </node3>
    </node2>
</node1>
```

For this I use this XSLT script (which is in the same directory as file2.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node2">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')//node2" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use MSXL processor, when I executes the script I have this output :

> Error occurred while executing stylesheet
>
> Code:   0x800c0006
>
> System error: -2146697210.

How I can obtain my result xml file ?

Comment: Which version of MSXML is that? I think MSXML 6 is by default configured to not allow the use of the `document` function. So you would need to configure it to enable the use by setting a second level property `AllowDocumentFunction` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I used the version 4.0

Comment: Is the XSLT file in the same directory as the XML documents? If not, then use `document('file2.xml', /)//node2`.